# Does my merge sort implementation has divide and conquer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, logic, mergesort

I was told in an interview to write a program for implementing merge sort on the concept of divide and conquer.

I wrote the below program,

```
var myGlobalArray = undefined;

myGlobalArray = [8,4,17,2,1,32];
example01(myGlobalArray);

myGlobalArray = [48,14,17,2,11,132];
example01(myGlobalArray);

myGlobalArray = [45,14,5,2,1,12];
example01(myGlobalArray);

myGlobalArray = [45,-14,-5,2,1,-12];
example01(myGlobalArray);

myGlobalArray = [38,27,43,3,9,82,10];
example01(myGlobalArray);


function example01(myArray){
   var mainArray = [];

   createSubArray(myArray,0);

   mainArray = mergeArrays(mainArray);
   console.log(mainArray[0]);

   // creates an array which contains n arrays for n numbers present in myarray
   // i.e. if array = [ 34, 1, 27, 3 ] that the below method will return
   // [ [34], [1], [27], [3] ]
   function createSubArray(subArray,index){
        var localArray = [];

        if(subArray[index] !== undefined){
            localArray.push(subArray[index]);
            mainArray.push(localArray);
            createSubArray(subArray,++index);// performs division recursively   
        }       
   }//createSubArray


   // merge the arrays present i.e. 
   // if gblArray = [ [2,5], [1,7] ] 
   // then the below method will return
   // an merged array [ [1, 2, 5, 7] ]
   function mergeArrays(gblArray){
        var mergedArrays = [],
            main_array = gblArray,
            arr = [], 
            counter = 0, 
            nextCounter = 0;

        do{

            while(counter < main_array.length){
                nextCounter = counter + 1;

                if(main_array[nextCounter] !== undefined){
                    arr = mergeAndSort(main_array[counter],main_array[nextCounter]);    
                    mergedArrays.push(arr);
                }else{
                    mergedArrays.push(main_array[counter]);
                }
                counter = nextCounter + 1;
            }

            main_array = mergedArrays;
            mergedArrays = [];  
            counter = 0;
            nextCounter = 0;

        }while(main_array.length > 1);

        return main_array;
   }//mergeArrays


   // merges two array and sorts i.e.
   // if array1 = [23,1] and array2 = [4,12] than
   // the below method returns [1,4,12,23]
   function mergeAndSort(array1,array2){
        var array2Counter = 0, 
            array1Counter = 0, 
            mergedArray = [];

        while(array2Counter < array2.length && array1Counter < array1.length){

            if(array2[array2Counter] < array1[array1Counter]){
                mergedArray.push(array2[array2Counter]);
                array2Counter++;
            }else{
                mergedArray.push(array1[array1Counter]);
                array1Counter++;
            }
        }

        while(array1Counter < array1.length){
            mergedArray.push(array1[array1Counter]);
            array1Counter++;
        }

        while(array2Counter < array2.length){
            mergedArray.push(array2[array2Counter]);
            array2Counter++;
        }

        return mergedArray;
   } //mergeAndSort



}//example01
```

If I run the above code, 
the output is

```
[ 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 32 ]
[ 2, 11, 14, 17, 48, 132 ]
[ 1, 2, 5, 12, 14, 45 ]
[ -14, -12, -5, 1, 2, 45 ]
[ 3, 9, 10, 27, 38, 43, 82 ]
```

But by looking at my above implemented merge-sort program, the inteviewer said that if doesn't follows divide and conquer concept.

I tried to convince him that method "mergeArrays" and "mergeAndSort" 
do the divide and conquer. But he didn't agreed.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: This might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange. In general, merge sort is as simple as `sort = merge(sort(first-half),sort(second-half))`, your solution looks overly verbose in the first place.

Comment: `mergeAndSort` should be called `merge` only

Answer (score 0):

The definition of divide and conquer on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) is:

> an algorithm design paradigm based on multi-branched recursion. A divide and conquer algorithm works by recursively breaking down a problem into two or more sub-problems of the same or related type, until these become simple enough to be solved directly. The solutions to the sub-problems are then combined to give a solution to the original problem.

Your solution does divide, and does combine the solutions to give the final solution, but it does not perform the divisions recursively, making the sub problems *gradually* smaller.

**Edit**: you *do* use recursion, but not in the way intended here. Your recursion is [*tail-recursion*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-tail-recursion-Why-is-it-so-bad), chopping off the smallest unit (they are not gradually getting smaller), and repeating that chopping via a chain of recursive calls, which could just as easily be performed in a loop.

Your solution is a [bottom-up approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation), while *divide and conquer* is commonly understood as a [top-down method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation). Although both methods are valid implementations of merge sort, strictly speaking, only one of them uses the *divide and conquer* paradigm.

But in a broader interpretation, *divide and conquer* can just as well be bottom-up, relaxing some of the requirements in the definition quoted above. So this may in the end be a matter of opinion.

Comment: The wiki article on divide and conquer links to it's merge sort article as an example, and the merge sort article includes bottom up merge sort. `breaking down a problem into two or more sub-problems` should include breaking down a problem into n sub-problems for an array of size n. The issue is if zero recursion could be considered as a case of recursion, similar to doing a top down merge sort with an array size of 1 element.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me a matter of opinion. If zero recursion could be seen as a case of recursion, then there would be no need to mention it in the definition, and all algorithms would fit a definition that has recursion in it.

Comment: You could consider a top down merge sort that divides an array into k >= 2 sub-arrays at each level of recursion, then merges the k sub-arrays upon return. Bottom up would be similar to top down with k == n, using this analogy.

Comment: Yes, with a constant *k >= 2* that fits indeed top-down definition, but with *k==n* you eliminate -- by design -- the recursion. It is a boundary case, and a matter of opinion whether this still fits the definition.